# Use relative binding to bind prop Window.ActualHeight to DoubleAnimation.To prop

Tags: wpf, animation, binding, relativesource

I try use relative binding and bind Window.ActualHeight property to DoubleAnimation.To property.

Relative binding doesn’t work but if I use binding by ElementName it work.

**NOT WORK:**

```
<Window xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="Sample.Window"
        x:Name="Shell"
        Title="Sample"
        Width = "525"
        Height = "350">

    <Canvas Height="400">
        <Ellipse Canvas.Left="80"
                 Canvas.Top="0"
                 Width="30"
                 Height="30"
                 Fill="LimeGreen">
            <Ellipse.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Ellipse.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                                             Duration="0:0:5"
                                             RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                             AutoReverse="True"
                                             To="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=ActualHeight}" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Ellipse.Triggers>
        </Ellipse>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

**THIS WORK:**

```
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                                         Duration="0:0:5"
                                         RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                         AutoReverse="True"
                                         To="{Binding ElementName=Shell, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
```

It is possible use relative binding to Window.ActualHeight property ?

**EDITED:**

I tested again on routed event Ellipse.Loaded animation not work but if I changed routed event to MouseEnter animation work. I posted all project.

[sample download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzxehQBcZZsNY19iWWtYZlBjVjQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank

Comment: I am guessing that the visual tree does not place `<DoubleAnimation>` under `<Window>`, so the `RelativeSource` binding doesn't find it when it walks up the visual tree from `<DoubleAnimation>`. That's just a guess though, I haven't tested it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely if any `frameworkElement traverses Visual Tree till ancestral window`, in that case `DoubleAnimation too is able to find ancestral window` but if no element is referring to ancestral window, DoubleAnimation is not able to traverse up the Visual tree.

In your sample in case i simply traverse till window outside of animation, it works. Test this sample (`traverse tree using Tag property of canvas`)-

```
<Canvas Height="400"
        Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                  AncestorType=Window}}"> <-HERE
   <Ellipse Canvas.Left="80"
            Canvas.Top="0"
            Width="30"
            Height="30"
            Fill="LimeGreen">
      <Ellipse.Triggers>
         <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Ellipse.Loaded">
             <BeginStoryboard>
                 <Storyboard>
                   <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                                    Duration="0:0:5"
                                    RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                    AutoReverse="True"
                                    To="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                                 AncestorType={x:Type Window}, 
                                                 Mode=FindAncestor}, 
                                                 Path=ActualHeight}" />
                  </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger>
       </Ellipse.Triggers>
    </Ellipse>
 </Canvas>
```

Comment: Sorry for mistake with Height and ActualHeight. Window Height property is set to 350 (look at XAML). Relative binding not work for ActualHeight also for Height.

Comment: I tested again on routed event Ellipse.Loaded animation not work but if I changed routed event to MouseEnter animation work. I posted all project. You fire event trigger on what event?

Comment: Event doesn't matter. Visual Tree will be same no matter what event you bind to. By the way it worked for me for `Ellipse.Loaded` event only.

Comment: So we must have a different code I don’t believe that same code on my pc not work and on your works :)

Comment: Have you tried testing it in fresh WPF app? Or may be you can use a converter in your binding just to be make sure that value is binding evaluated to.

Comment: Ok i have one button which is referring to Visual Tree and traversing upto window. If i remove that button it stops working. I guess in case no element traverses up the tree, animation part is unable to traverse up the tree to find ancestral window.

Comment: Ok, Yes if I added one button with relative binding to window, animation work on routed event Ellipse.Loaded. Also if Ellipse property has binding to Window for example for Stroke property also work. (Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=Background}").

Comment: Yeah if any sibling or parent accesses visual tree then it gets passed on to animation i guess.

Comment: hmm it is very strange. binding in animation works only if element in which is defined animation has binding or parent or siblings has binding.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that too till today.:)